# How can I get the internal "message" value of a System.Exception?

Tags: c#, exception, reflection

I have an FTP exception thrown from a third-party assembly which is quite generic:

```
Exception of type 'JSchToCSharp.SharpSsh.jsch.SftpException' was thrown.
```

On inspection of the Exception, I see there is a private/internal member called **message** (lower-case m) that contains my error message:

[image: FTP Exception]

How can I get the value of this **message** member?

I have tried to use reflection to get it but null is returned from **GetValue**:

```
    BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic
        | BindingFlags.Static;
    FieldInfo field = type.GetField(fieldName, bindFlags);
    var value = field.GetValue(instance);

    return value.ToString();
```

It doesn't appear to be **Non-Public** or **Static** so I'm a little unsure as to what to use as my **BindingFlags**.

Thanks

Comment: @SonerGönül that will return `Exception of type ...` as specified in the breakpoint

Comment: Which SSH library is this?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov it's JSchToCSharp.SharpSSH

Comment: Is it open source? Where did you take it from?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov a simple Google search points to http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx (I might be wrong) :o)

Comment: @balexandre Yeah, I looked at that, but didn't see where `JSchToCSharp` came from. Thx

Comment: This library is pretty borken, it completely fails to initialize its Exception base class.  Fixing it is best.  The `message` member is otherwise a public field, using the default binding flags is good enough.  Or just plain catching the SftpException so you don't have to use reflection.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov I'm not sure about it to be honest, it was an existing library in an existing project that I have inherited.

Comment: @SuitedAces See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're printing out `SftpException.Message` instead of `SftpException.message` (notice the lowercase *m*).

The author of the library thought (for an unknown reason) that it is a good idea to expose a public *field* called `message` instead with the same name as a property called `Message`, which is from the `Exception` base class, but contains different content.

This example:

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        throw new SftpException(1, "hello");
    }
    catch (SftpException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.message);
    }
}
```

Yields "hello".

Note you can also use the `ToString` on the custom `SftpException` for it to print the actual error message. This would also work:

```
Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
```

**Side note:**

I used ILSpy to look at the `SftpException` class to see the access modifier of the `message` field. It looks like this:

[image: ILSpy image of SftpException class]

Comment: @Suited, why do you think `message` is private/internal member? @Yuval, bad library costs too much time.

Comment: @qxg I think he *assumed* it was private because the debugger represents it as a *field*, and usually, fields aren't public.

Comment: I for some unknown (silly) reason was catching a JSchException even though it's there in black and white as a SftpException! The message field obviously wasn't present in JSchException so assumed it must be private. This works great Yuval! And as does Balexandres answer if I catch the correct exception!!

Answer (score 1):

from your breakpoint you could see that the `Exception` is not a general exception, it has a known type, so you could actually catch that Exception type as:

```
try {
    ... 
} 
catch(JSchToCSharp.SharpSsh.jsch.SftpException ex1) {
   // I'm sure that ex1.Message will have what you need
}
catch(Exception ex2)
{
  // for any other Exception types...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure. What if `SftpException` didn't call `base(message)`?

Comment: you need to see the code, but I'm almost sure that `SftpException` inherits from [`Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) to behave like that, that will suffice...

Comment: I'd tried this already but just tried again and unfortunately, ex1.Message gives me the same "Exception of type 'JSchToCSharp.SharpSsh.jsch.SftpException' was thrown."

Comment: SftpException should be like this: `public SftpException(string message) : base("Exception is thrown at here.") { this.message = message; }`. Message property will not help here.

Comment: Thank you sir. I was being an idiot and catching the wrong exception type. This does indeed work.